# How to split the column values of dataframe into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

Below is my dataframe having a column that are merged together,

```
   PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR
0  700\nDaewoo 8000  Gearless   
1  300\nHyundai 4400  Gearless   
2  600\nSTX 2600  Gearless   
3  200\nB170 \nGeared   
4  362 Wenchong 1700 Mk II \nGeared   
5  252\nRichMax 1550  Gearless   
6  220\nCV 1100 Plus \nGeared   
7  232\nOrskov Mk VII  Gearless   
8  119\nKouan 1000  Gearless   
9  100\nHanjin 700  Gearless
```

I want to split the columns into three different columns namely PLUGS, DESIGN, GEAR. Is there any way to do this?

Below is the code which i tried:

```
new_df[['PLUGS', 'DESIGN', 'GEAR']] = new_df['PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR'].str.split(' ')
                print(new_df)
```

expected output:

```
   PLUGS  DESIGN               GEAR
0  700    Daewoo 8000          Gearless   
1  300    Hyundai 4400         Gearless   
2  600    STX 2600             Gearless   
3  200    B170                 Geared   
4  362    Wenchong 1700 Mk II  Geared   
5  252    RichMax 1550         Gearless   
6  220    CV 1100 Plus         Geared   
7  232    Orskov Mk VII        Gearless   
8  119    Kouan 1000           Gearless   
9  100    Hanjin 700           Gearless
```

Comment: What is your original CSV? How did you read the file? @Saran

Comment: I extracted this information from a pdf using camelot

Comment: Is it possible to have the raw text and not the dataframe please?

Comment: Is `df["PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR"].str.extract(r"^(\d+)[\\n\s]+([^\\]+)[\\n\s]+(.+)$")` working on real data?

Comment: No :( @MustafaAydın

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks - (Provide original csv data)

Comment: @MustafaAydın,  regex should be working, i have reproduced the same data a little manipulation on the regex, and it works.

Comment: @KarnKumar Sorry for the late response... Indeed regex seems to work. Thanks for the answer, +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your Dataframe :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR': ['700\nDaewoo 8000  Gearless', '300\nHyundai 4400  Gearless', '600\nSTX 2600  Gearless', '200\nB170 \nGeared', '362 Wenchong 1700 Mk II \nGeared', '252\nRichMax 1550  Gearless'], }, 
...                   index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) 
>>> df
    PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR
0   700\nDaewoo 8000 Gearless
1   300\nHyundai 4400 Gearless
2   600\nSTX 2600 Gearless
3   200\nB170 \nGeared
4   362 Wenchong 1700 Mk II \nGeared
5   252\nRichMax 1550 Gearless
```

You can indeed use the `split` method on several separators, here `\n` and `space`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(df['PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR'].str.split('\n| '))
    PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR
0   [700, Daewoo, 8000, , Gearless]
1   [300, Hyundai, 4400, , Gearless]
2   [600, STX, 2600, , Gearless]
3   [200, B170, , Geared]
4   [362, Wenchong, 1700, Mk, II, , Geared]
5   [252, RichMax, 1550, , Gearless]
```

Then, you can assign the first and last element to the correct column, and the rest to the `DESIGN` column :

```py
>>> df['PLUGS'] = df['PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR'].str[0]
>>> df['DESIGN'] = df['PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR'].str[1:-1]
>>> df['GEAR'] = df['PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR'].str[-1]
>>> df
    PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR                         PLUGS   DESIGN                      GEAR
0   [700, Daewoo, 8000, , Gearless]             700     [Daewoo, 8000, ]            Gearless
1   [300, Hyundai, 4400, , Gearless]            300     [Hyundai, 4400, ]           Gearless
2   [600, STX, 2600, , Gearless]                600     [STX, 2600, ]               Gearless
3   [200, B170, , Geared]                       200     [B170, ]                    Geared
4   [362, Wenchong, 1700, Mk, II, , Geared]     362     [Wenchong, 1700, Mk, II, ]  Geared
5   [252, RichMax, 1550, , Gearless]            252     [RichMax, 1550, ]           Gearless
```

The last thing to do is to improve the `DESIGN` column to map it as a string instead of a list using the `join` method, and drop the `PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR` column like so :

```py
>>> df['DESIGN'] = df['DESIGN'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, x)))
>>> df.drop(['PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR'], axis=1)
    PLUGS   DESIGN               GEAR
0   700     Daewoo 8000          Gearless
1   300     Hyundai 4400         Gearless
2   600     STX 2600             Gearless
3   200     B170                 Geared
4   362     Wenchong 1700 Mk II  Geared
5   252     RichMax 1550         Gearless
```

Answer (score 2):

As Suggested in the comment section, the regex should work pretty well here,

### DataFrame Sample:

```
>>> df
                   PLUGS\nDESIGN\nGEAR
0        700\nDaewoo 8000  Gearless
1       300\nHyundai 4400  Gearless
2           600\nSTX 2600  Gearless
3                200\nB170 \nGeared
4  362 Wenchong 1700 Mk II \nGeared
5       252\nRichMax 1550  Gearless
6        220\nCV 1100 Plus \nGeared
7      232\nOrskov Mk VII  Gearless
8         119\nKouan 1000  Gearless
9            100\nHanjin 700  Gearless
```

Just removing the newline char from the column name to make readability easy for use as well.

```
>>> df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r"\\n", " ", regex=True)
```

Now, Column name does not have any special cars:

```
>>> df
                     PLUGS DESIGN GEAR
0        700\nDaewoo 8000  Gearless
1       300\nHyundai 4400  Gearless
2           600\nSTX 2600  Gearless
3                200\nB170 \nGeared
4  362 Wenchong 1700 Mk II \nGeared
5       252\nRichMax 1550  Gearless
6        220\nCV 1100 Plus \nGeared
7      232\nOrskov Mk VII  Gearless
8         119\nKouan 1000  Gearless
9            100\nHanjin 700  Gearless
```

Now, we can use [pandas.Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). While using `regex` method, all the Named groups `()` will become column names in the result.

As, the named group will become columns with predefined names like `0,1,2` thus we can rename them altogether with desired names to get the desired result as follows:

```
>>> df = df['PLUGS DESIGN GEAR'].str.extract(r"^(\d+)[\\n\s]+([^\\]+)[\\n\s]+([\\n|^Gear][a-z]+)").rename(columns={0: 'PLUGS', 1: 'DESIGN', 2: 'GEAR'})
```

### Result:

```
>>> print(df)
  PLUGS                DESIGN      GEAR
0   700          Daewoo 8000   Gearless
1   300         Hyundai 4400   Gearless
2   600             STX 2600   Gearless
3   200                 B170     Geared
4   362  Wenchong 1700 Mk II     Geared
5   252         RichMax 1550   Gearless
6   220         CV 1100 Plus     Geared
7   232        Orskov Mk VII   Gearless
8   119           Kouan 1000   Gearless
9   100           Hanjin 700   Gearless
```

regex Explanation:

You can check at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

```
(\d+)[\\n\s]+([^\\]+)[\\n\s]+([\|^Gear][a-z]+)
```

**1st Capturing Group (\d+)**

```
    \d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
    + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    Match a single character present in the list below [\\n\s]
    + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
    n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
    \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
```

**2nd Capturing Group ([^\]+)**

```
    Match a single character not present in the list below [^\\]
    + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
    Match a single character present in the list below [\\n\s]
    + matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
    \\ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)
    n matches the character n literally (case sensitive)
    \s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
```

**3rd Capturing Group ([|^Gear][a-z]+)**

```
Match a single character present in the list below [\|^Gear]
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
^Gear matches a single character in the list ^Gear (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below [a-z]
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
a-z matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: This is nice Sir, one liner with regex.